# how to connect Power BI Report Builder to Azure SQL DB

Tags: powerbi

I am creating a paginated report (i.e., Power BI Report Builder, not Power BI Desktop).  I am trying to connect to a DB in an Azure SQL MI instance in Azure US Gov cloud.  I choose the 'Azure SQL Database' connection type, I enter my server name, and I try to select a DB.  However, when I try to select a DB, it keeps looping through the "sign-in" windows.  That is, it prompts me for my MS account, it then takes me to my organization's sign-in page (where I select my account), and then it repeats with the MS account sign-in.  The same thing happens when I click on the 'Test Connection' button.  How can I resolve this?

If it matters, I am able to successfully connect to the same Azure SQL MI DB in Power BI Desktop (via the 'Azure SQL database' connector, Microsoft account credential type, and DirectQuery mode).  So, the issue must be something specific to Power BI Report Builder.

Comment: This works for me, but I can't test in Gov.  If you can test from another computer, try that.  Otherwise you may need to open a support case.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  Thank you.  Unfortunately, I can't test from another computer.   But, it's good to know that it's nothing due to PBI Report Builder itself.